# Ignore Daylight Savings on old dates with Python

Tags: python, datetime, dst, pytz

I am currently taking a date (already at local time) and converting it to utc time like so with python:

```
import pytz, datetime
tz = pytz.timezone(tz_str)
d_tz = tz.normalize(tz.localize(date))
d_utc = d_tz.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

But some of the dates I have are within the US and from before 1966 when Daylight Savings Time was established. For these dates, I would like to convert to UTC ignoring Daylight Savings. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The time zones returned by `pytz` should be intelligent enough to know if the date was before DST was established and do the right thing automatically.

Comment: P.S. I think the problems you're having are because you misunderstand when Daylight Savings Time was established. See http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/history.html

Comment: They don't seem intelligent enough Mark. I did a few tests to check. The Daylight Savings Time is applied in the same way before 1966 as after. I have a "date" from before 1966 which I can assume was written in a context of no Daylight Savings.

Comment: From your article: "In the United States, DST caused widespread confusion from 1945 to 1966 for trains, buses and the broadcasting industry because states and localities were free to choose when and if they would observe DST. Congress decided to end the confusion and establish the Uniform Time Act of 1966 that stated DST would begin on the last Sunday of April and end on the last Sunday of October. However, states still had the ability to be exempt from DST by passing a local ordinance."

Comment: Do you know the history of the particular location you're testing well enough to know when it transitioned? From your use of the word "assumed" I presume you do not. You can look at the time zone database that `pytz` relies on to see what kind of detail it contains.

Comment: Hmm I'll take a look for the particular location.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems that "Chicago" did have DST then - but that little place within the Chicago time zone most likely didn't. So it might just be very tricky because there is no way to identify not to use DST.

Comment: The tz database says that [it is not complete before 1970](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/fc861a9e137c63e1b0d562ad09d0dd5f4d8e798f/CONTRIBUTING) though I see [there are timezone rules for Chicago since 1920](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/fc861a9e137c63e1b0d562ad09d0dd5f4d8e798f/northamerica#L305). You should probably use the tz database i.e., trust it if it says there is DST and submit a patch if you know a better source.